# Firefox doesn't render one character with imported font (Chrome does it well)

Tags: fonts, firefox, google-chrome

I've run into an issue with Firefox. Check out the example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BuLhF.

Basically, with the font *Poiret One*, embedded with Google fonts, the letter `ō` doesn't render properly in Firefox but in Chrome it is ok.

Edit:

Screenshot:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B58rXlxeBUsIMXo1MnJrRFczbFk/edit?usp=sharing.

Moreover, on Virtual Machine Ubuntu, Firefox is displaying it ok. The host Windows 7 has this problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  Both firefox and chrome render the character just fine on my system (Ubuntu Linux).

Comment: I'm with Stephen - works OK for me. Firefox on Windows 7 (and Chrome for that matter). Your screenshot doesn't just show an "improper rendering" - it's showing a character from an entirely different font!?

Comment: My fault. I forgot that I have installed a subset of this font and the system is getting it without trying to update it from the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit was in fact me.

I had earlier **installed a smaller subset** of this font on my machine. Firefox and Internet Explorer (this is as far as I have checked) are rendering a font from the system, yet **Chrome downloads** the font even if you already have it.